# How to implement controller level versioning having inheritance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, versioning

I have below controller structure -
1. ValuesController : Controller
2. ValuesV2Controller : ValuesController
3. ValuesV3Controller : ValuesV2Controller
4. ValuesV4Controller : ValuesV3Controller

All controllers having one common method Get(Type value); to get a perticular record.
Type of value differs in every controller.

I have implemented versioning in ASP.NET Core Web APIs with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning Nugget.

In startup > Configure services; included below set of code -

```
services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
        {
            o.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-lz-api- 
version");
            o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            o.ReportApiVersions = true;
            o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
         });
```

When we invoke V1, V2, V3 APIs then it gives 500 not found an error, specifically for Versioning performed with custom Header.

Tried out below possible solutions :
1. Making base class virtual and overriding derived classes from them, but as type differs, it doesn't work.
2. This problem doesn't occur for URL versioning, this is very specific to custom header versioning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need multiple controllers and inheritance to achieve what you are trying to do. You can simply have a controller with different action methods. Then you define the `[ApiVersion]` attribute for each action.

```
[Route("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")
    public IActionResult GetV1()
    {
    }

    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    public IActionResult GetV2()
    {
    }

    // and so on ..
}
```

If your controller supports multiple versions, you can map the action to the specific version.

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    public IActionResult GetV1()
    {
    }

    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    public IActionResult GetV2()
    {
    }

    // and so on ..
}
```

If you must have multiple controllers, you can define the `[ApiVersion]` for each controller. Or you can set the conventions in Startup file

```
services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
{
    o.ReportApiVersions = true;
    o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);

    o.Conventions.Controller<ValuesController>().HasApiVersion(new ApiVersion(1, 0));
    o.Conventions.Controller<ValuesV1Controller>().HasApiVersion(new ApiVersion(2, 0));
});
```

You can also add conventions for the specific Action as well, by using the `o.Conventions.Controller<ValuesController>().Actions` method.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @user2357818 let me know if you have more questions. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Actually, the problem statement is I cannot avoid inheritance. I have V1, V2 controllers, and in future there could be many more. In V1 there are few methods like Get, Post and in V2 even I have only Put method, I should be able to access Get & Post methods when I invoke V2 endpoint.

Comment: Can you please share your controllers code? If it's possible for you to upload the code to GitHub? I am unable to understand why you can't avoid inheritance. This is not the usual way of using the controllers.